# Does the Firestore .NET SDK automatically make conditional updates by default?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore

If a Firestore document is deserialized to a POCO with an update timestamp, like so

```
    [FirestoreDocumentUpdateTimestamp]
    public Timestamp UpdateTime { get; set; }
```

Does a subsequent update/replacement of the document using this POCO see the update timestamp and prepare a conditional operation such that if the stored document has been changed meanwhile, then it fails?

I ask because it seems (to me) like desirable, safe default behaviour.

Comment: According to your question, it might be best to consult this situation in the [.NET SDK Github repository ](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet). Also, I was wondering if you already tried it on your own.

You can also try to write the same document just like the following [documentation explains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: I've not been able to try yet. Still not got it working. Not sure if it's just me but for 20 years nothing in software dev has ever just worked. I seem to hit a whole slew of problems that don't Google. It's like I'm perpetually every product's first customer.